# How do torrents work?

Tags: protocols, bittorrent

Can anyone explain to me or find me an article online, explaining in technical details how torrents work, which technology is used in creating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project sites are a good place to start: http://www.bittorrent.com/

Answer (score 5):

See the [bittorrent protocol specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html).

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia is usually a good place to start: [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29)